# Swr's cache updates but UI doesn't for no reason - swr hook Next.js ( with typescript )

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, swr

I'm doing a facebook clone, and everytime i press like's button, i want to see the change immediately, that's something that swr provides, but, it only updates after 4-8 seconds :/

**What i tried to do is the following**: when i click like's button, i first mutate the cache that swr provides, then i make the call to the API, then  revalidate data to see if everything is right with the data, actually i console log the cache and it updates immediately, but it the UI doesn't and i don't know why

Let me give sou some context with my code

This is how my publication looks like ( inside pub it's the likes property )

```
export type theLikes = {
  identifier: string;
};

export type theComment = {
  _id?: string;
  body: string;
  name: string;
  perfil?: string;
  identifier: string;
  createdAt: string;
  likesComments?: theLikes[];
};

export interface Ipublication {
  _id?: string;
  body: string;

  photo: string;

  creator: {
    name: string;
    perfil?: string;
    identifier: string;
  };

  likes?: theLikes[];

  comments?: theComment[];

  createdAt: string;
}

export type thePublication = {
  data: Ipublication[];
};
```

This is where i'm asking for all publications with getStaticProps

```
const PublicationsHome = ({ data: allPubs }) => {
  // All pubs

  const { data: Publications }: thePublication = useSWR(
    `${process.env.URL}/api/publication`,
    {
      initialData: allPubs,
      revalidateOnFocus: false
    }
  );


  return (
    <>
      {Publications ? (
        <>
          <PublicationsHomeHero>
            {/* Create pub */}
            <CreatePubs />
            {/* Show pub */}
            {Publications.map(publication => {
              return <Pubs key={publication._id} publication={publication} />;
            })}
          </PublicationsHomeHero>
        </>
      ) : (
        <div></div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`${process.env.URL}/api/publication`);

  return {
    props: data
  };
};

export default PublicationsHome;
```

This is where the like button is ( focus on LikePub, there is where the logic is )

The conditional is simple, if user already liked a pub, cut the like, otherwise, like the pub

```
interface IlikesCommentsProps {
  publication: Ipublication;
}

const LikesComments: React.FC<IlikesCommentsProps> = ({ publication }) => {

const LikePub = async (): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      if (publication.likes.find(f => f.identifier === userAuth.user.id)) {
        mutate(
          `${process.env.URL}/api/publication`,
          (allPublications: Ipublication[]) => {
            const currentPub = allPublications.find(f => f === publication);

            const deleteLike = currentPub.likes.findIndex(
              f => f.identifier === userAuth.user.id
            );

            currentPub.likes.splice(deleteLike, 1);

            const updatePub = allPublications.map(pub =>
              pub._id === currentPub._id ? currentPub : pub
            );

            return updatePub;
          },
          false
        );
      } else {
        mutate(
          `${process.env.URL}/api/publication`,
          (allPublications: Ipublication[]) => {
            const currentPub = allPublications.find(f => f === publication);
            currentPub.likes.push({ identifier: userAuth.user.id });

            const updatePub = allPublications.map(pub =>
              pub._id === currentPub._id ? currentPub : pub
            );

            return updatePub;
          },
          false
        );
      }
      console.log(publication.likes);
      await like({ identifier: userAuth.user.id }, publication._id);
      mutate(`${process.env.URL}/api/publication`);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err) {
        mutate(`${process.env.URL}/api/publication`);
      }
    }
  };

return (

      <motion.div
          onClick={LikePub}
          variants={Actions}
          whileHover="whileHover"
          whileTap="whileTap"
        >
              <motion.span>
                <LikeIcon colorIcon="rgb(32, 120, 244)" />
              </motion.span>
              <LikeCommentText
                separation="0.2rem"
                colorText="rgb(32, 120, 244)"
              >
                Me gusta
              </LikeCommentText>
        </motion.div>

)
}
```

As you can see as well, i console.log publication's likes, and this is what happened

[image]

The identifier is added to the cache, meaning that user liked the pub, but the UI doesn't update, it takes 4 - 7 seconds to update, probably even more, the same thing happened with removing the like, look at this

[image]

Cut the like, but, the UI doesn't update

I'm desperate, i've tried everything, i've been trying to fix this for almost a week, but found nothing, what am i doing wrong, is this a bug ?

Comment: To confirm, you do get the UI update it's just delayed?

Comment: Exactly, the UI waits until the trigger at the end to update cache :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is you're directly mutating (in the javascript not swr sense) swr's data that is completely invisible to swr. And only when response is returned from the API your state is updated and that finally triggers swr's observers.

---

Here you may notice that `currentPub.likes` is an array (reference) inside `currentPub` object. You're directly mutating it (with `splice`) and then insert **the same** reference back into `allPublications` object. From swr's perspective the `likes` array didn't change. It still holds the same reference as before the mutation:

```ts
(allPublications: Ipublication[]) => {
    const currentPub = allPublications.find(f => f === publication);

    const deleteLike = currentPub.likes.findIndex(
        f => f.identifier === userAuth.user.id
    );

    currentPub.likes.splice(deleteLike, 1);
    const updatePub = allPublications.map(pub =>
        pub._id === currentPub._id ? currentPub : pub
    );

    return updatePub;
}
```

Snippet to illustrate the behavior:

```js
const allPublications = [{ attr: 'attr', likes: [1, 2, 3] }]
const currentPub = allPublications[0]
currentPub.likes.splice(1, 1)
const updatePub = allPublications.map((pub, idx) => idx === 0 ? currentPub :  pub)

console.log(updatePub[0] === allPublications[0]) // true
console.log(updatePub[0].likes === allPublications[0].likes) // true. the reference stays the same
console.log(updatePub[0]) // while the object has changed
```

You should rewrite it to exlude direct mutation and always return changed references for changed objects/arrays. Something like:

```js
(allPublications: Ipublication[]) => {
    const currentPub = allPublications.find(f => f === publication);

    const likes = currentPub.likes.filter( // filter creates new array (reference)
        f => f.identifier !== userAuth.user.id
    );
    const updatePub = allPublications.map(pub => // map creates new array
        pub._id === currentPub._id ? { ...currentPub, likes } : pub // {} creates new object (reference)
    );

    return updatePub;
}
```

```js
const allPublications = [{ attr: 'attr', likes: [1, 2, 3] }]
const currentPub = allPublications[0]

const likes = currentPub.likes.filter((el) => el !== 2)
const updatePub = allPublications.map((pub, idx) => 
  idx === 0 ? { ...currentPub, likes } :  pub
)

console.log(updatePub[0] === allPublications[0]) // false
console.log(updatePub[0].likes === allPublications[0].likes) // false
console.log(updatePub[0])
```

And do the same for `else` branch mutation function.

Comment: aleksxor, thank you so much for your answer, you are the first person that responded me, i'll try this answer later, i'll let you know with a checkmark if it worked, thanks again man !

Comment: @aleksxor they are getting the data change though? This is a delay issue, not a stale data issue I believe.

Comment: If you've worked with redux you'd know that non-changed reference is not triggering data refresh. There are no deep structure checks there for performance reasons. Whether object has changed or not is decided by referential equality.

Comment: Yes, I understand the ref checks, but as he is pushing the data from client -- surely that data, according to my understanding, is then propagated to all subscribers of the key. The fact that he does actually see the data change, albeit delayed, highlights this?

Comment: The object refs  finally change when client gets actual response (after `await like(...` runs `mutate` without callback that means the swr updates the structure itself (correctly this time). But he expects them to change right on `mutation`. And they can. He just need to make sure the refs does not stay the same.

Comment: Ey, aleksxor, the answer worked, now it updates so much faster, now i'm having other issues, but the main problem is gone, it took me a week to get you, damn, thanks  man !!